# Missing ; before statement (Google Cal to Google Form)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm getting the error "Missing ; before statement. (line 2, file "Code")". I'm not a programmer, but i found a code that gives me the possibility to embed a G Cal on G Form.
So, please be gently :)

anticipated thanks!

```
//this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar settings page of the calendar in question
02  var calendarId = XXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com;
03   
04  //below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)
05  var startDtId = 4;
06  var endDtId = 5;
07  var titleId = 3;
08  var descId = 2;
09  var formTimeStampId = 1;
```

Comment: Are those line numbers _in the actual code_? If so delete them.

Comment: deleted now...the same error. In fact i think there were the numbers and the quotes. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar            settings page of the calendar in question
02  var calendarId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com";
03   
04  //below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)
05  var startDtId = 4;
06  var endDtId = 5;
07  var titleId = 3;
08  var descId = 2;
09  var formTimeStampId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

String (non-numeric) values must be enclosed in quotes...

```
var calendarId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com";
```

Also, see what Boris the Spider (interesting username :) said in the question comments about the line numbers.